# Which API is used by the official Facebook for Android application?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I currently use the Graph API and it seems like it has many bugs.

Example (Missing Posts):

1. Query "home" using the Graph API Explorer (with all permissions granted).
2. Look at the posts shown in Facebook website or the Facebook Android application (both set to show recent posts first).
3. Compare the result and you will probably see some posts missing (it can be missing videos, photos or just simple text statuses).

I recently published a question regarding another problem (Graph API returns some hidden posts). So it returns posts that it shouldn't and ignores posts that it should.

Obviously there is a way to get all items correctly but I've researched this issue for a long time and it seems like the Graph API is simply not the solution.
I'm wondering if anyone else have seen these kind of issues using the Graph API and if switching to FQL helped. Knowing which API is used by Facebook's official application will hopefully put an end to the pure Graph API vs FQL question.

EDIT: Answering my original question - The Facebook for Android application is using FQL. Yet I would like to know if it's possible to show a correct 1-1 reflection of the stream/wall using just the Graph API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Facebook apps use undocumented and generally unavailable api's.  From monitoring and decrypting the network traffic, it's mostly fql calls, however they have access to data and methods that arent available to third party developers. So you will often find discrepancies such as this when using the feed. However, I usually find that fql and graph return the same result, but a different feed than Facebook.com and their mobile apps.

Comment: I've made a lot of tests and found that FQL and Graph does not return the same data. Actually using FQL and querying using filter_key='others' returns a result that is much closer to the news feed (unlike the result when filtering as documented in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). Can you explain what 'others' means in detail? The docs lack this information.